# How to remove wrong command ran earlier?

Tags: command-line, error-handling

I ran command from Noobslabs.com

```
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu precise main
```

but mistyped to

```
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu precise main ain
```

now this wrong command is preventing other apps to work properly and any app i use crashes after sometime.

Problem shown is:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.

Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and 
include the following error message:
    'E:Type 'ain' is not known on line 3 in source list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-themes-precise.list']"
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
sudo sed -i 's/ ain//' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-themes-precise.list
```

Otherwise, run `sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-themes-precise.list` and fix the line manually.

Comment: 1st command is not working I also tried 2nd command but I don't know how to save command after editing command line.?